# Next view in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I am creating an application in AngularJs.
I have created a demo application to implement this feature http://plnkr.co/edit/zZApdZYgutpd2M8Ju4jR?p=preview

In this application there are two link **Mobile view** and **Desktop view**
when we click on Mobile view it is showing interface as to be shown in Mobile devices ( i.e the first interface override by second one.)

when we click on Desktop view it is showing interface as to be shown in Desktop devices ( i.e a left menu having detail in middle of page.)

But I think config.js can be written in more better way and redirection to other pages should be in some other possible way than that of using

**$state.current.data != undefined && $state.current.data.parent == 'Desktop'**

I am new with angularJs please suggest a standard way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Check [angular-responsive](https://github.com/lavinjj/angular-responsive) for a responsive design directives, this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bDuQ-TlyE8c) present how to use it.